# How to properly delete pointer from a std::list?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, delete-operator

I'm creating an object via `new`, then later adding the pointer to an std::list once the object is set up.

What is the correct way of deleting a pointer and erasing the data from the list without causing memory leaks?

Comment: No, you should use smart pointers.

Comment: What is the type of `m_DataList` ?

Comment: Is the extra `;` in the `while` line a typo, or is it intentional? If it is intentional, then you have a problem.

Comment: @ahenderson `m_DataList` contains `datalist*`, not `datalist`, so the delete is necessary

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to delete a vector pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855534/best-way-to-delete-a-vector-pointer)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manual loop to search the element, I would rather use `std::find_if`

```
auto it = std::find_if(lst.begin(), 
                       lst.end(), 
                       [&val](datalist const &d) { return d.index == val; });

if ( it != lst.end() )
{
    delete *it;
    lst.erase(it);
}
```

That is not to say that you're doing it incorrectly.

However, your code will improve if you consider using some form of smart points, such as `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or boost's smart pointers, then you don't have to manage memory yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your `std::list` to hold `datalist` instances instead of `datalist*` pointers, then you don't have to `delete` the `datalist` instances manually anymore.  When you remove an element from a `std::list` (or any other STL container, for that matter), the element's data is freed automatically for you.  If the element is a class/struct with a destructor defined, the destructor will be called.

Try this:

```
std::list<datalist> m_DataList;
```

.

```
datalist AR; // <-- local variable on the stack, freed when out of scope
AR.index = ...;
AR.number = ...;
mylist.push_back(AR); // <-- pushes a copy-constructed instance of the variable
```

.

```
std::list<datalist>::iterator Iter1 = m_DataList.begin();
while(Iter1 != m_DataList.end()) 
{ 
    if (Iter1->index == m_SomeVar)     
    { 
        m_DataList.erase(Iter1); // <-- copied datalist instance is freed automatically
        break; 
    } 

    ++Iter1; 
}
```