# best way to delete a vector pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to properly delete pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854274/how-to-properly-delete-pointer)

i'm using `std::vector` to put a group of objects into it for later use, i am using `DETAIL* pPtr = new DETAIL` to create the pointer, and then inserting it into the vector.

the struct of DETAIL

```
struct DETAIL {
    int nRef;
    short sRandom;
};
```

Is this the best way to delete and erase a pointer **within a vector** leaving no room for memory leaks?

```
while(Iter1 != m_Detail.end())
{
    if((*Iter1)->nRef == m_SomeVar)    
    {
        delete  *Iter1;
        m_Detail.erase(Iter1);
        break;
    }

    Iter1++;
}
```

Comment: It is almost always wrong to maintain a pointer to a vector and/or a vector of pointer types.  (Almost) always.  Don't do it.

Comment: didn't u ask this question a couple of hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854274/how-to-properly-delete-pointer

Comment: If your vector contains raw pointers, there's absolutely nothing you can do to protect it if the vector is destroyed by an exception for example. The possibility of leaks is always there.

Comment: Note that you don't "delete a pointer". You delete an *object* to which you have a pointer, by calling a `delete` expression on that pointer.

Comment: Note: the duplicate is about `list` whereas this is about `vector` . If you are using raw pointers then there are some differences in how you should delete a single element.

Answer (score 9):

Don't put raw pointers into the `vector`, instead use smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr`. Then there is no need for `delete`, simply `erase` the pointer from `vector` and the pointed object will be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use std::shared_ptr remove the shared pointer from the vector using erase and let it take care of deallocation.  However there is nothing wrong with what you are doing but erase does not cause the vector to release the space it has allocated to hold the pointer.  You can use [shrik_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) to remove that allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

> i am using `DETAIL* pPtr = new DETAIL` to create the pointer

That's your first mistake, you're acquiring a resource (memory from the freestore and an object constructed in that memory) and not initializing an object that will take ownership and guarantee to deallocate the resources you acquired. The idiom to solve that first mistake is called [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

It should be something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<DETAIL> pPtr(new DETAIL);
```

Or better yet:

```
std::shared_ptr<DETAIL> pPtr = std::make_shared<DETAIL>();
```

Or in C++03 replace `std::shared_ptr` with `boost::shared_ptr` (and `boost::make_shared`)

The next mistake is `delete  *Iter1;` because almost any code that uses `delete` outside of a destructor is wrong (and **all** code that uses `delete` outside a destructor and is accompanied by a question about how to avoid memory leaks is definitely wrong.)  If you use the RAII idiom you don't need to use `delete` because it happens automatically at the right time.

Also, why is your class called `DETAIL`? What's wrong with `Detail` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like answer like "never do" so I'll answer, but gives you some tricks to bypass the risk of freeing the vector without freeing the content.

if I understand well you have a vector of DETAIL pointers:

```
std::vector<DETAIL*> details;
```

So you want a method to remove and delete all pointed objects which refer to a certain m_SomeVar: (for now let's imagine it's a free function)

```
void free_references(int reference, std::vector<DETAIL*> & vector)
{
    std::vector<DETAIL*>::iterator it = vector.begin();

    while (it != vector.end())
    {
        if ((*it)->nRef == reference)
        {
            delete *it;
            // erase() makes the original 'it' in an unknown state which can't be used
            // erase will return a valid iterator which is, in this case, the following element
            it = vector.erase(it); 
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand in your code, the vector is member of a class. Which is good cause you'll be able to delete everything in the destructor.

However, I would use `std::unique_ptr` here to "give" the ownership of the pointer to the unique_ptr container inside the vector. And when the vector memory is free, the `std::unique_ptr` smart point make sure that the owned pointed object is freed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if i fully understood it but have you tryied using the ZeroMemory macro?

Comment: I don't understand this response.

Comment: ZeroMemory in a MSVC macro only used to set a block of contiguous memory to 0. This CAN'T be used with std containers.